# Align bput on ncline

Tags: pstricks

I wanna place some text below a line. So I'm using `\bput`. Works great, but text is always centered. Is there a way to align it left / right? See the picture for better bellow.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,dvips]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-eps}

\begin{document}    

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{TeXtoEPS}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,runit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,-8.3)(16,0.0)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, linewidth=1pt](0,-8.3)(16,0.0)
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}

    \psframe[fillstyle=none, linewidth=0pt](0.5,-0.6)(15.5,-3.0)
    \pcline[linestyle=solid, linecolor=black]{<->}(1.0,-1.5)(15.0,-1.5)
    \bput*{:U}(0.1){LongerWord1}
    \bput*{:U}(0.5){LongerWord2}
    \bput*{:U}(0.90){LongerWord3}

    \psframe[fillstyle=none, linewidth=0pt](0.5,-3.6)(15.5,-6.0)
    \pcline[linestyle=solid, linecolor=black]{<->}(1.0,-4.5)(15.0,-4.5)
    \bput*{:U}(0.1){Short1}
    \bput*{:U}(0.5){Short2}
    \bput*{:U}(0.90){Short3}

\end{pspicture}

\end{TeXtoEPS}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for accepting answers to all your questions! Generally, upvoting *all* helpful answers (to your questions as well as to others you read) is strongly encouraged. This way, we get a more precise rating which answers are more helpful and which are less so. So it'd be great if you went over your questions and upvoted some of the answers. More info in our [faq#howtoask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\bput` is an obsolet command, use `\nbput` instead. Aligning is not really possible with `\nbput`, but you can use `\rlap` or `\llap` or `\rput` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{helvet}\renewcommand\familydefault{phv}

\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(0,-8.3)(16,0.0)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid, linewidth=1pt](0,-8.3)(16,0.0)
    \psset{linewidth=2pt}

    \psframe[fillstyle=none, linewidth=0pt](0.5,-0.6)(15.5,-3.0)
    \pcline[linestyle=solid, linecolor=black]{<->}(1.0,-1.5)(15.0,-1.5)
    \rput*[lb](1.0,-2.05){LongerWord1}
    \nbput*{LongerWord2}
    \rput*[rb](15.0,-2.05){LongerWord3}

    \psframe[fillstyle=none, linewidth=0pt](0.5,-3.6)(15.5,-6.0)
    \pcline[linestyle=solid, linecolor=black]{<->}(1.0,-4.5)(15.0,-4.5)
    \nbput*[npos=0]{\rlap{Short1}}
    \nbput*{Short2}
    \nbput*[npos=1]{\llap{Short3}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: High-rep users changing their gravatar confuse me `:)`